# PHP - Retrieving IPs from host names

Tags: php, ip, host, gethostbyname

I am retrieving values from a table field and appending a string to it to get a list of host names.  I would then like to loop through all the host names and return the IP for each.

The following code gets my host names:

```
$sql = "select * from table order by col1 asc";

$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() ." " . $sql);

// Loop through table and append .zzz to each col1.
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

    $host_name = $r['col1']. ".zzz" . " ";

    //echo $host_name;
}
```

The above code works as it should, but I am unsure how to retrieve the IPs for each host name.  I have been trying gethostbyname but can't get it to work correctly.  I know I have to loop through the host name values.  Would I use a foreach loop?  I have tried that and can't get it working.  Can someone give me some pointers please.

I have tried the following but it doesn't return anything:

```
$host_name_ip = $host_name;
foreach ($host_name_ip as $name) {
    $ip = gethostbyname($name);
    echo '<li>' . $ip. '</li>';
}
```

I have also tried this... again, nothing:

```
foreach($host_name as $url) {
    $ip = gethostbyname(trim($url)); 
}

echo $ip;
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$host_name` in your initial loop. Change it to be an array and your foreach will work.

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $host_name[] = $r['col1']. ".zzz";
}
```

To print the host name and it's address in your loop use:

```
foreach ($host_name_ip as $name) {
    $ip = gethostbyname($name);
    echo '<li>' . $name . ' is at address ' . $ip. '</li>';
}
```

You don't even need to store the names in an array. Just do everything you need in your while loop.

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $ip = gethostbyname($r['col1']. ".zzz");
    echo '<li>' . $r['col1']. '.zzz' . ' is at address ' . $ip. '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It now returns values to the page but returns the host names and not the IPs.

Comment: What is in the `col1` column in your database? If it is a host name remove everything after the `]` on the left side of the = in my answer (leaving the `;` of course).

Comment: There are 5 letter variables in col1 for each row.  Appending 'zzz' gives me my host name.   (zzz is just a sample)

Comment: OK then remove the `. " "` after the `.zzz`. you don't need/want it any more.

Comment: I do have a couple issues with this still. It's returning the IPs which I wanted, but I'd like to be able to print each host name plus each corresponding IP to the page.  I can't seem to get this working.  It won't print the host name after I removed the ." " as suggested in your last comment.  Also, when the IPs display on the page, the word "Array"  displays before each ip.  I would like to see 'host name - IP', but right now I just see 'Array111.111.11.11', for example.

Comment: I can remove "Array" in front of the IP, but what is putting the word array there is what I thought would add the host name.  This is my current Foreach loop which returns all the IPs.  This comes after the While loop you have in your initial answer above.     $host_name_ip = $host_name;

    foreach ($host_name_ip as $name) {
        $ip = gethostbyname($name);
        echo '<li>'. $ip. '</li>';

Comment: Dave, thanks again.  This works perfectly!  Appreciate the help!